# debian login screen

Tags: debian, kali-linux, login, repository

It's not a big problem but I wondering why this happened.
I installed 32-bit Debian without GUI as a primary OS but I added Kali Linux repos "add new source list called 'kali.list' with kali packages source and it works " but when I booting the System the login screen displayed "Kali GNU/Linux Rolling .... " .
My question is why this message tells me that the system is kali ,before I add the repo it was Debian instead Kali.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian

Comment: Most of the tools in kali can be installed independently without using the Kali repos. Many tools are actually in the Debian repo, or you can pull the code/scripts down from github if they aren't in the repo

Answer (score 3):

This means you “upgraded” at least part of your system to Kali (specifically, at least the `base-files` package).

It’s generally a bad idea to add other distributions’ repositories to a Debian system; see [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) for details.

Answer (score 2):

By adding the kali repositories, you effectively gave APT a new source for all system packages.

Because the versions of the packages on Kali's repositories are newer than the ones you had installed from the debian repositories, (I'm guessing you installed debian stable) it's most likely that you inadvertently upgraded your system's packages with the ones from the kali repositories.

It's possible to selectively mix and match packages from different repositories by using package pinning, but it is a sure way of breaking your system if you do not understand what you are doing.

Doc:

- https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList
- https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian
- https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration

Happy linuxing.